# How to return only text after a comma in a string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am extracting text between parens in the active window title bar. That part is working great (thanks to some help I received here previously!). Now I want to create two separate macros - one that returns only the first name, and the other that returns only the last name.

My active window title bar looks something like this:

some text to the left (HENDERSON,TOM) some text to the right
(there is no space after the comma)

The last name macro works perfectly. It looks like this:

```
Sub a1LastName()
    'Extract last name of patient from title bar (between parens)
    Dim strPatientName As String
    Dim OpenPosition As Integer '(open paren marker)
    Dim closeposition As Integer '(close paren marker)
    OpenPosition = InStr(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption, "(")
    closeposition = InStr(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption, ")")
    strPatientName = Mid(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption, _
        OpenPosition + 1, closeposition - OpenPosition - 1)
    Dim c As Long
    c = InStr(strPatientName, ",")
    strPatientName = Left(strPatientName, c - 1)
    Selection.TypeText strPatientName
End Sub
```

The second macro is identical to the first, except that the second-to-last line of code has a "Right" instead of a "Left" instruction:

```
Sub a1FirstName()
    'Extract first name of patient from title bar (between parens)
    Dim strPatientName As String
    Dim OpenPosition As Integer '(open paren marker)
    Dim closeposition As Integer '(close paren marker)
    OpenPosition = InStr(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption, "(")
    closeposition = InStr(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption, ")")
    strPatientName = Mid(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption, _
        OpenPosition + 1, closeposition - OpenPosition - 1)
    Dim c As Long
    c = InStr(strPatientName, ",")
    strPatientName = Right(strPatientName, c - 1)
    Selection.TypeText strPatientName
End Sub
```

Here's my problem: The "first name" macro always returns the last name minus the first four characters, followed by the first name, instead of simply the first name.

The only examples I'm able to find anywhere in Google land are specifically for Excel. I have combined through my VBA manuals, and they all give similar examples as I have used for extracting the text to the right of a character.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Split()` to create an array out of the comma-separated parts of the text, then access either the first or second part:

```
Sub a1LastName()
    Dim strPatientName As String
    strPatientName = ParensContent(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption)
    If strPatientName Like "*,*" Then
        Selection.TypeText Trim(Split(strPatientName, ",")(0))
    End If
End Sub


Sub a1FirstName()
    Dim strPatientName As String
    strPatientName = ParensContent(ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption)
    If strPatientName Like "*,*" Then
        Selection.TypeText Trim(Split(strPatientName, ",")(1))
    End If
End Sub

'Utility function: find and return text enclosed by ()
'   Return empty string if no () found
Function ParensContent(txt) As String
    Dim rv As String, pos As Long, pos2 As Long
    If txt Like "*(*)*" Then
        pos = InStr(1, txt, "(")
        pos2 = InStr(pos, txt, ")")
        rv = Mid(txt, pos + 1, (pos2 - pos) - 1)
    End If
    ParensContent = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Very thorough.  You can also get away with using `Split` exclusively instead of `InStr` and `Mid`.  It's a little less tolerant of a missing `)` or `(` though.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like everyone has keyed in on `Split` to get the first/second part of the name.  You can also use `Split` to get rid of the parentheses.  This works if you know that you will only (and always) have a single `(` and `)`.

**Code** gives the main idea.  You can use `Split` to get the part of the `String` which does not include the `(` or `)` and then do it again to get either side of the `,`.

```
Sub t()

    Dim str As String
    str = "(Wall,Byron)"

    Dim name_first As String
    Dim name_last As String

    'two splits total
    name_last = Split(Split(str, "(")(1), ",")(0)
    name_first = Split(Split(str, ")")(0), ",")(1)

    'three split option, same code to remove parentheses
    name_last = Split(Split(Split(str, "(")(1), ")")(0), ",")(0)
    name_first = Split(Split(Split(str, "(")(1), ")")(0), ",")(1)


End Sub
```

The code above presents a `two Split` and a `three Split` option.  The main difference is that the three Split variety uses the same code to strip off the parentheses, and the only change is which side of the `,` to grab.  The two Split options take advantage of the fact that splitting on a comma removes one the parentheses for free.  The indices there are a little more complicated.

Comment: I would use split for the comma but to simply remove the brackets I would use replace: name_last = replace(replace(Split(str, ",")(1),")",""),"(","") and name_first = replace(replace(Split(str, ",")(0),")",""),"(","") Your 3 split option will give you issues if there isn't a bracket

Comment: @DanDonoghue, I agree with just a single character to remove, split is a little overkill. Replace is more obvious what you're trying to do. I have used this pattern before for less trivial stripping and it works well. In this case it would beat replace if there was other text outside the brackets. If that's not likely, replace would be a good way to go.

Comment: @DanDonoghue, replace also has the advantage of failing nicely if nothing is found. Definitely good for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: You are right, it comes down to the master data, rather than replace we could even use mid combined with the len of the string minus 2 if we are guaranteed that there is always a starting and ending bracket and nothing else, the split method does give a bit more dynamic ability if the recordset requires it.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT it seems I didn,t understand well the first time. Attempt 2:

You want to remove everything right of the comma.

```
Mystr = Left(Mystr,  Instr(Mystr, ","))
Mystr = Mid(Mystr, 2)
```

the second line uses mid to take everything after the first char (the parentesis)

---

You're looking for the Mid function.

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/string-manipulation.html#mid

Use it like so:

```
Debug.Print Mid("abcde", InStr("abcde", "c"))
```

Will return "cde"

I used Instr to locate where it should start from instead of writing a number. To get it after the comma, use:

```
Debug.Print Mid(Mystring, InStr(Mystring, "," + 1))
```

Where Mystring would be your string. I wrote +1 so it starts after the comma.

Comment: Be careful in your last example, because if there're no commas in the string it will return the full string instead of an empty one (which would be more sane).